# Spring Autowire a Static Interface class

Tags: java, spring, static, autowired

***How can i Autowire a static interface class***

**This is my Code**

```
@Autowired
private static IAuditLogRepository iAuditLogRepository;

public static int saveLog(LogFile logFile){
iAuditLogRepository.saveLog(logFile);  // Autowireing fails and iAuditLogRepository is null.
}
```

**My interface class**

```
public interface IAuditLogRepository {
    public Serializable saveLog(LogFile logFile);
}
```

***How can i Autowire the interface.?***

*I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659875/autowired-and-static-method). How can i do the same for an interface class.*

Comment: Why does it have to be static?  Make it non-static and move on.

Comment: Its a logging mechanism which runs even before anyone logs in. Its linked with many functions like cron job etc.!!

Comment: yes everything i am currently working on is for making it in a good shape. But Cant change it to a non static one its used in lots of places.!! Will consider your suggestion once we are done with the current modifications.

Comment: @duffymo autowiring a static class is okie but its an interface ..!! That's why i am asking..!!Its not a duplicate... I itself provided a similar link in the Question.

Comment: @duffymo Could you please explain how this becomes a duplicate..!!

Comment: @Vitaly lol dude..!! I have linked the duplicate question in my own answer huh..!! Try to read the question fully before marking it as duplicate.Please click on the `this`  in the last line of my post.

Comment: @Dileep dude.. Did not you notice that the answer is the same? The same problem - the same solution with PostConstruct.

Comment: @Vitaly I am sorry i haven't seen the last Answer. The accepted answer was not a possible solution for an interface..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `@Autowired` a static field. But there is a tricky skill to deal with this:

```
public class Foo {

private static IAuditLogRepository iAuditLogRepository;

@Autowired
private IAuditLogRepository iaRepos;

@PostConstruct
public void someFunction () {
iAuditLogRepository = iaRepos;
}


public static int saveLog(LogFile logFile){
iAuditLogRepository.saveLog(logFile); 
}


}
```

In one word, `@Autowired` a instance field, and assign the value to the static filed when your object is constructed.

Comment: will try and get to you now..!!

Comment: not possible i tried both on constructor and post construct

Comment: !!Sorry it works fine on `postConstruct` Thanks Dude ;-)

Comment: Are you sure the instance field is autowired? BTW, the `Foo` object must be managed by Spring as well. @Dileep

Comment: Ok, gland to help. @Dileep

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not allowed comments, I will post answer:
Use a singleton instead of static methods here.

Comment: using another option will be considered later, but right now i need a fix not an alternative.

Comment: I do not know how to fix it keeping it static. Sorry.