# Factory Pattern when Constructor of the Implementation has Dependencies to Inject

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, factory-pattern

I'm working on a private stuff and I faced an issue where I need other opinion. I have the following code where I want to make a factory pattern the create new instance of `PaymentStrategy`:

### `PaymentStrategy` interface

```
public interface PaymentStrategy {

  Optional<Payment> pay(String payerAccountNumber,
                        String sellerAccountNumber,
                        ProductOrder[] productOrder
  );
}
```

### `EmployeePaymentStrategy`implementation which has two dependencies

```
public class EmployeePaymentStrategy implements PaymentStrategy {

  private final ProfileRemoteProvider profileRemoteProvider;
  private final PaymentValidator      paymentValidator;

  @Autowired
  public EmployeePaymentStrategy(ProfileRemoteProvider profileRemoteProvider,
                                 PaymentValidator paymentValidator) {
    this.profileRemoteProvider = profileRemoteProvider;
    this.paymentValidator = paymentValidator;
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Payment> pay(String payerAccountNumber,
                               String sellerAccountNumber,
                               ProductOrder[] productOrder) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to know how to deal with dependencies in a Factory class. 
Is the `EmployeePaymentStrategy` class the right place to inject those two dependencies?
Is the Factory Pattern is best way to solve problem

### `PaymentStrategyFactory` where I have the issue

```
public class PaymentStrategyFactory {

  private PaymentStrategyFactory() {
  }

  public static PaymentStrategy getPaymentStrategy(AccountType payerAccountType,
                                                   AccountType sellerAccountType) {
    if (sellerAccountType == AccountType.COMPANY) {
      switch (payerAccountType) {
        case EMPLOYEE:
          return new EmployeePaymentStrategy(...); //TODO 
        case BASIC_USER:
          return ...
        default:
          //this exception is throw when a payer account type is unknown
          throw new RuntimeException("exception type will be more specific");
      }
    }
    //This exception is throw when a seller account type is not a seller
    throw new RuntimeException("exception type will be more specific");
  }
}
```

Comment: you should not use `new EmployeePaymentStrategywhich`, but call your DI framework to instantiate instance of EmployeePaymentStrategywhich bean

Comment: Thanks the idea. I updated my Post with your proposal. It this code thread safe now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `PaymentStrategyFactory` UPDATED and WORKING

```
public class PaymentStrategyFactory {

  private static ApplicationContext context;
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  private PaymentStrategyFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  private void initializeApplicationContext() {
    PaymentStrategyFactory.context = applicationContext;
    this.applicationContext = null;
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    PaymentStrategyFactory.context = context;
  }

  public static PaymentStrategy getPaymentStrategy(AccountType payerAccountType,
                                                   AccountType sellerAccountType) {
    if (sellerAccountType == AccountType.COMPANY) {
      switch (payerAccountType) {
        case EMPLOYEE:
          return context.getBean(EmployeePaymentStrategy.class);
          // return new EmployeePaymentStrategy();
        case BASIC_USER:
           ...
        }
     } 
     throw ...
   }
}
```

Additionally to the comment of Ilya below, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659875/autowired-and-static-method/17660550#17660550) help me to deal with static member when using Spring for DI (Dependencies Injection). Now everything look fine for me.