# Can a Spring Bean class contain static methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I hope this isn't too noob of a question, I'm still quite new to Spring. Can a bean class contain static methods? My initial thoughts is no because a static method is global, there's one instance per the entire application and threads to share but a bean might not be defined as such.

I tried searching for this question but couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: Of course a class **can** contain static methods. A better question is *should* it contain static methods. And there (as you note) a static method is global, and there's one instance per the entire applicate (that is, they are Singletons). As such, you must ensure any static methods are thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

A spring bean may have static methods too.

**Using constructor @Autowired**

```
@Component
public class Boo {

    private static Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    public Boo(Foo foo) {
        Boo.foo = foo;
    }

    public static void randomMethod() {
         foo.doStuff();
    }

    public static int getThree(){
         return 3;
    }
}
```

You may also do it this way:
**Using @PostConstruct to hand value over to static field**

The idea here is to hand over a bean to a static field after bean is configured by spring.

```
@Component
public class Boo {

    private static Foo foo;
    @Autowired
    private Foo tFoo;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Boo.foo = tFoo;
    }

    public static void randomMethod() {
         foo.doStuff();
    }
}
```

source: [@Autowired and static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659875/autowired-and-static-method)

Answer (score 0):

It can be contained.

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestDao testDao;

    public static void test(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @PostMapping("test")
    public String test(){
       TestService.test();
       return "ok";
    }
}
```