# Spring Autowire a static factory method

Tags: java, spring

Say I have a class

```
class Service {
    private final Repository repository

    @Autowired
    public Service(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository
    }
}
```

It autowires the repository class. Say I wanted to change it to also add something dynamically and I would like to do it through a static factory method while also maintaining my dependency. I would try to do something like this:

```
class Service {
    private final Repository repository;
    private String field;

    @Autowired
    public Service(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository
    }

    private Service() {}

    public static Service of(String field) {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.setField(field);
        return service;
    }

    private void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

But this code won't work because the `repository` wont actually be instantiated.

Is there any way for me to be able to both inject a spring dependency and a dynamic attribute?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't `@Autowire` a static content with Spring.

Comment: I think spring create by default  singleton bean/instance of all the components, if your repository is annotated with any stereotype it would be instantiated  by spring container

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659875/autowired-and-static-method, this can be helpfull

Comment: You're back to tight coupling if you do that. Just inject your factory where needed.