# Using Spring Data Repositories in static methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-repositories

I defined 2 classes.

*AndroidPush.java*

```
public class AndroidPush {

    private static String SERVER_KEY = "XXXXX";
    private static String DEVICE_TOKEN = "XXXXX";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String title = args[0];
        String message = args[1];
        sendPushNotification(title, message);
    }
    private static void sendPushNotification(String title, String message) throws Exception {
        String pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" +
                title +
                "\",\"message\":\"" +
                message +
                "\"},\"to\":\"" +
                DEVICE_TOKEN +
                "\"}";
        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());
    }
}
```

And

*NotificationProcessing.java*

```
public class NotificationProcessing {

    private static NotificationRepo notificationRepo;

    @Autowired
    public NotificationProcessing(NotificationRepo notificationRepo) {
        NotificationProcessing.notificationRepo = notificationRepo;
    }

    public static void addNotification(Offer offer) throws Exception {
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setId(null);
        notification.setMessage("There is new offer: " + offer.getTitle());
        notification.setLink("/offers/" + offer.getId());
        notificationRepo.save(notification);

        String[] arguments = new String[] {"New Offer", notification.getMessage()};
        AndroidPush.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

I call my repository inside static method like [Francisco Speath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001027/francisco-spaeth) answered on this question [@Autowired and static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659875/autowired-and-static-method)

But then, if I try to call my method and store notification I am getting this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null

on this line: `notificationRepo.save(notification);`

I suppose this is because using repository inside of static method, but if I remove static from everywhere and try to access addNotification() method there is another error:

> non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

I'm calling this addNotification() method inside my RestController

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Offer newOffer (@RequestBody Offer offer) {
    NotificationProcessing.addCampaignNotification(offer);
    return repo.save(offer);
}
```

So what is solution for using repository inside static method?

Comment: Why do you want to use `addNotification` as a static method?

Comment: sincerely, I don't want to use this method as a static, but if I remove static there is this second ERROR : "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" and I am not able to run application at all. So if there is any suggestion to avoid this error when I am not using static and explanation why is it happening, it would be useful

Answer (score 3):

The referenced question handles about how to reference an instance field injected by Spring from a static method.
As `static` modifiers don't have any access to instance fields, it may make sense.
But that is not the standard, it is a workaround for legacy code or libraries where it sounds complicated or not possible to make the static method an instance method.

> I suppose this is because using repository inside of static ethod,
>   but if I remove static from everywhere and try to access
>   addNotification() method there is another error:
>
> *non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context*

You are on the wrong way.
To use bean dependencies you need to inject them where you need them in other beans.
You will never define methods with `static` modifier in a bean and invoke it from another bean by prefixing the class.
Beans are instances. These are not related to the class itself.

Besides if  `notificationRepo.save(notification);` triggers a NullPointerException, it means a single thing : your class is not a bean spring because here the Spring context will not be successfully loaded if the `notificationRepo` dependency cannot be resolved :

```
@Autowired
public NotificationProcessing(NotificationRepo notificationRepo) {
    NotificationProcessing.notificationRepo = notificationRepo;
}
```

Long story short, annotate your class to make it a Spring Bean and remove all these static modifiers :

```
@Component
public class NotificationProcessing {
    ...
}
```

And inject this in this way in the controller :

```
private NotificationProcessing notificationProcessing;

public MyController(NotificationProcessing notificationProcessing){
  this.notificationProcessing = notificationProcessing;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Offer newOffer (@RequestBody Offer offer) {
    notificationProcessing.addCampaignNotification(offer);
    return repo.save(offer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is invoked when you create an instance of your object so it looks illogical to mark a constructor with @Autowired and use the injected instances from the static context. As I see `NotificationProcessing` is not marked as `@Component` so I'm not sure that it is handled by the container at all.

I'd recommend you removing the `static` modifiers from `notificationRepo` and `addNotification()`, marking the class as `@Component` and invoke `addNotification()` from the injected instance of `NotificationProcessing`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `NotificationProcessing.addCampaignNotification(offer);` to `notificationProcessing.addCampaignNotification(offer);` and inject the `notificationProcessing` into your controller by adding the following constructor:

```
@Autowired
public YourController(NotificationProcessing notificationProcessing) {
    this.notificationProcessing= notificationProcessing;
}
```