# Using @Autowired services in static method

Tags: java, spring, static, autowired

I am trying to autowire multiple services (around 10-15) in a class having static methods and came across a solution mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17660550) about using `@Autowired` constructor. Can we use constructor @Autowired approach for multiple classes as well?

For  example, suppose I have two classes `Foo1` and `Foo2`. Can I use the single constructor for both classes like

```
@Component
public class Boo {

    private static Foo1 foo1;
    private static Foo2 foo2;

    @Autowired
    public Boo(Foo1 foo1, Foo2 foo2) {
        Boo.foo1 = foo1;
        Boo.foo2 = foo2;
    }

    public static void randomMethod() {
         foo1.doStuff();
         foo2.doSomeOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Or is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes you can, but it generally is a very bad idea, for one or two or any number of classes. Mutating the static field is a bad idea, there is no guarantee that the constructor is called before `randomMethod` is called, potentially causing a NPE.

Comment: @Bhagyesh do you know what 'static' is or does? the obvious answer here, is no

Comment: Also, having 10 to 15 dependencies in one class, is a clear indicator of a bad code structure. This violates the Single Responsibility Principle and will make it harder for you or your colleagues to maintain the code.

Answer (score 0):

Spring + `static` is a very bad idea.

I suggest making the `randomMethod()` not `static` and then inject `Boo` everywhere you earlier had to call the `static` method. E.g change this:

```
class A {
    public void run() {
        Boo.randomMethod();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
@Component
public class A {
    private final Boo boo;

    @Autowired
    public A(Boo boo) {
        this.boo = boo;
    }

    public void run() {
        boo.randomMethod();
    }
}
```

This construct is the spring intended way, and I suggest you to use it.